# VoiceRecognitionService sample doesn't work

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition

I'm trying to get the `VoiceRecognitionService` from [the samples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html) to work.
The settings part of it works just fine, I can choose between 'Letters' and 'Numbers', but whenever I hit the microphone on the soft-keyboard, the default Google voice recognizer is used.

I'm testing on my HTC Desire S. There's no microphone-button on the soft-keyborad on the AVDs.